# Quitar Action Bar de un solo Layout

Tags: android

queria saber como hacer para quitar el action bar de un solo Layout, pero que en los demas si este.  POr ejemplo, en la pantalla de inicio de sesion de la aplicacion que no este el Action bar, pero una vez iniciada la sesion y que cambie de layout si aparezca el action bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con esto en tu Manifest:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Claro dependiendo en la actividad que quieras.

O desde el código de la actividad que quieres:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); //o en su caso getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```